# Rounded and shadow for block

Tags: beamerposter, shadows, rounded-corners

I have  style for my block:

```
\setbeamertemplate{block begin}{
\vskip.75ex
\begin{beamercolorbox}[leftskip=1em,colsep*=.75ex]{block title}%
\usebeamerfont*{block title}\insertblocktitle
\end{beamercolorbox}%
{\ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body}{}{\nointerlineskip\vskip-0.5pt}}%
\usebeamerfont{block body}%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=.75ex,sep=.75ex,vmode]{block body}%
\ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body}{\vskip-.25ex}{\vskip-.75ex}\vbox{}%
}
\setbeamertemplate{block end}{
\end{beamercolorbox}\vskip1ex
}
```

Is possible to make it rounded and with shadow?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: With no MWE added this is really not likely to get answered: please edit one in and request reopening.